# Renderizar Mostrar mi componente con React

Tags: reactjs

Necesito que este componente se presente o renderice en mi pagina, lo llamo desde mi App principal, pero no lo hace y no me da error. Pueden darme alguna idea o logica de como hacerlo.

```
import React from "react";
import { useState } from "react";

export const Prueba2 = () => {
const [nombre, setNombre] = useState("");
const [apellido, setApellido] = useState("");
const [estado, setEstado] = useState([]);

function addUser(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    const usuario = {
        nombre : nombre,
        apellido : apellido
    }
    setEstado([...estado, usuario]);
}    

return (
<>
    <form action="" onSubmit={(e)  => addUser(e)} >
        <input onChange={(e) => setNombre(e.target.value) } type="text" id="nombre" name="nombre"></input>
        <input onChange={(e) => setApellido(e.target.value) } type="text" id="apellido" name="apellido"></input>
        <button > regist</button>
    </form>               

</>
);
```

}

Comment: "Me da error" no nos dice absolutamente nada. Qué error te da? Por favor añade todos los detalles posibles si quieres que te podamos ayudarte, no somos adivinos.

Comment: Algo tonto lo q pregunto, pero has importado el componente en app?

Comment: Claro que si. Tengo otro componente que solo muestra palabras y se lo muestra por pantalla

Comment: Muestra el código del componente padre y como importas, saludos